# Modelando banco com Herança com JPA

Tags: jpa-2.0

Eu entendo o conceito de Herança, atualmente estou trabalhando com um projeto de administração de condomínio, e me encontro na seguinte questão como você podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor desconsidere a tabela Dívidas, o meu problema em questão é a tabela Condomino, Sindico, Morador e Proprietario. O Sindico, Morador e Proprietario são um tipo de Condomino, porque eu sei que se tivesse que colocar os mesmos atributos que estão em Condomino e colocasse em Sindico, Morador e Proprietario ficaria redundante, é por isso que coloquei Condomino como Super-Class e as classes Sindico, Morador e Proprietario como Sub-Classe, ou seja, Condomino irá ser abstrata e as outras classes abaixo iram herdar os atributos da classe Condomino.

Sei abstrair tudo isso muito bem em UML, e também sei fazer isso em Java, em todas as classes coloquei as anotações do JPA como por exemplo do 
@NotBlank, e somente coloquei a anotação @Id, @GeneratedValue nas Sub-Classes porque a classe Condomino é uma classe abstrata.

A outra coisa que fiz foi somente colocar @Entity nas Sub-Classes pelo mesmo motivo da classe Condomino ser uma classe abstrata.

Será que dá forma que fiz está correto?
Será que quando for executar o projeto ele irá cria as minhas tabelas todas certinhas na base?

Se mesmo com a descrição que fiz abaixo for necessário colocar o código aqui nessa postagem, não se preocupe que coloco, mas eu acho que com as descrições que fiz acima dá para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente nestes casos nós utilizamos Agregação e não Herança. As implementações do JPA como o Hibernate não lidam muito bem com Herança.
Na prática, ficaria algo assim:

```
public class Condomino {
    // atributos omitidos
}

public class Sindico {
    // atributos omitidos

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "condomino_id")
    private Condomino condomino;
}
```

Para este caso, a classe Condomino não seria mais abstrata.

Leia mais em: http://uaihebert.com/jpa-mini-livro-primeiros-passos-e-conceitos-detalhados/20/

Comment: Que tipos de problemas eu poderia acontecer se eu fosse implementar herança nas minhas tabelas?

Comment: Por padrão não vai funcionar, você vai precisar de configurações adicionais. Aqui tem um post sobre o assunto com mais detalhes: http://blog.caelum.com.br/jpa-com-hibernate-heranca-e-mapeamentos/

Answer (score 0):

Implementando herança no jpa

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Condomino {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String nome,cidade,email;

    //todo getter setter

}
```

Classes que herdam de `Condomino`

Morador

```
@Entity
public class Morador extends Condomino {
    private Date inicioAluguel;
    private Float taxaReajuste,valor;

}
```

Sindico

```
@Entity
public class Sindico extends Condomino{

    private Date inicioMandato,fimMadato;

}
```

Proprietário

```
@Entity
public class Proprietario extends Condomino {

    private Date dataCompra;
}
```

Você tem 3 estratégias para implementar herança

- Uma tabela por classe: `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`
- Tabela única: `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`
- Indexada as tabelas: `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`

Vc escolhe de acordo com sua necessidade:

- Se vc quer performance e usar querys com polimorfismo a estratégia mais indicada é `Tabela única`, mas vc corre risco de inconsistência de dados.
- Se vc quer consistência, performance e querys com polimorfismo a melhor estratégia é `Indexação`.
- Se vc não precisa de polimorfismo ou querys de relacionamento a estratégia ideia é a `Uma Tabela Por Classe`, mas tenha em mente que vc não vai poder usar muito polimorfismo para criar querys complexas e isso pode gerar perda de consistência